# JavaScript Prototype Chain Reference to Object.prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I need some help for understanding the prototype chain. I don't understand / not quite sure if my assumptions are correct. I want to understand the link to the Object.prototype.
One example

```
function A(){};
var newObject=new A();
```

I know the newObject has an internal property [[prototype]] which has a reference to A.prototype.
And this prototype-Object has also an internal property with reference to Object.prototype, right?
But why does it have that reference? Is it because the prototype of A (used as constructor) is an object which can be imagined to be created by A.prototype=new Object() ( which will be done automatically in the background). And now I have a reference to the prototype of Object?
I hope I explained it clearly.
Please let me know your comments.

Many thanks

Comment: Every object has already prototype od `Object` in it, that's why you can do `({ a: 3 }).toString()` for example

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Well, not *every* object. `Object.create(null).toString()` won't work. (Just nitpicking.)

Comment: @FZs yes, js is known for misimplementing Java features. In Java `null.toString()` would work. They made `typeof null === 'object'` in JavaScript, but didn't really make it an object.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski That wasn't my point, but you're right. (`typeof null` being `'object'` is actually because of a kind-of bug in the first version of JS, and they standardized it because people relied on it by then. End of tangent.) I just wanted to say that *not every* object has `Object.prototype` in its prototype chain, even though most of them does.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

In JS, pretty much all the objects have a reference to `Object.prototype` in their prototype chain.

The `[[Prototype]]` of an object refers to `Object.prototype` as the end of a prototype chain. In your example, this means what you described:

```
            [[Prototype]]                  [[Prototype]]                   
newObject -----------------> A.prototype -----------------> Object.prototype
```

That applies to...

- objects created by the `Object` constructor (i.e. `new Object(...)`),
- those created with an object literal (which you can think of as syntax sugar for a `new Object()` call followed by a bunch of `Object.defineProperty` calls) and
- objects created internally by the JS interpreter (like `A.prototype` which is created automatically when you define the `A` function).

There are also exceptions of this "rule" though:

- `Object.prototype` itself.

  If it had a reference to... well, itself, it would create and infinite recursion when a nonexistent property is looked up. Hence, it has *no prototype*, which means that its `[[Prototype]]` is `null` (that's how a prototype chain "ends").
- Custom objects created using `Object.create` or modified with `Object.setPrototype`.

  The `[[Prototype]]` can be set to anything this way, including `null` or other objects whose prototype chain doesn't end with `Object.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed what the ECMAScript specification prescribes. When a function is defined with the `function` keyword, then an object is created from `Object.prototype` which is assigned to the function's `prototype` property, and therefor will be used as prototype for any object that is constructed by that function.

This specification can be found at [Make Constructor](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-makeconstructor), step 5.a:

> 5.a. Set *prototype* to OrdinaryObjectCreate(%Object.prototype%).

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to javascript every value is either an object (arrays, objects, sets, maps...) or a primitive(Numbers, strings, bool ...) objects and primitives are the two data types in javascript a . You have the Number, String , Array and even Object constructors which you can use to create the corresponding value.
And when you create new object using the new operator the following steps happen consecutively:

// 1. New empty object is created

// 2. the constructor function is called, and the this keyword is assigned to the empty object i.e this = {}.

// 3. the empty object is linked to the prototype of the constructor functio i.e {}.**proto** = constructorFunction.prototype.

// 4. the constructor function automatically return the new object {}.

keep in mind that constructorFunction.prototype is the prototype of the new object that is created from the constructorFunction and not of itself.

I hope this clears things up a little for you!

Comment: "*When it comes to javascript every thing is an object.*" no, primitives are not objects. There are object *wrappers* for primitives but the very fact *wrappers* exist suggests that not everything is an object.

Comment: Yes your actually right there are primitive and object data type, but that's not the point i'm trying to make here i'm just trying to explain what i understand about the prototypal inheritance to ma dude. so rather than taking my answer out of context why don't you provide him with a better explanation T!

Answer (score 0):

> But why does it have that reference?

To answer in one sentence - because prototype is an object itself and has its own prototype. When you create function in JavaScript it has a property called prototype. When you use that function as a constructor function (with `new` operator), new object is creating which as you wrote is linked to its constructor function prototype via internal [[prorotype]] property. That prototype object is plain JavaScript object which [[prototype]] property references Object.prototype.